# Not able to create Asset

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services, windows-media-services

I'm trying to use Windows Azure Media Service to upload a video using their REST API.

What i have done so far is that i have obtained an access_token successfully. Following [the guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973618.aspx) on their website, i now need to create an Asset. The [tutorial for this part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129593.aspx) tells me that i need to fire such request:

```
POST https://media.windows.net/API/Assets HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
x-ms-version: 2.1
Authorization: Bearer my-access-token
Host: media.windows.net
Content-Length: 27
Expect: 100-continue

{ "Name" : "NewJSONAsset" }
```

But my response is way different than the one provided in the guide. It looks like that:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://wamshknclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/api/$metadata",
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "AccessPolicies",
            "url": "AccessPolicies"
        },
        {
            "name": "Locators",
            "url": "Locators"
        },
        {
            "name": "ContentKeys",
            "url": "ContentKeys"
        },
        {
            "name": "Files",
            "url": "Files"
        },
        {
            "name": "Assets",
            "url": "Assets"
        },
        {
            "name": "IngestManifestFiles",
            "url": "IngestManifestFiles"
        },
        {
            "name": "IngestManifestAssets",
            "url": "IngestManifestAssets"
        },
        {
            "name": "IngestManifests",
            "url": "IngestManifests"
        },
        {
            "name": "StorageAccounts",
            "url": "StorageAccounts"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tasks",
            "url": "Tasks"
        },
        {
            "name": "NotificationEndPoints",
            "url": "NotificationEndPoints"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jobs",
            "url": "Jobs"
        },
        {
            "name": "TaskTemplates",
            "url": "TaskTemplates"
        },
        {
            "name": "JobTemplates",
            "url": "JobTemplates"
        },
        {
            "name": "MediaProcessors",
            "url": "MediaProcessors"
        },
        {
            "name": "Operations",
            "url": "Operations"
        },
        {
            "name": "Origins",
            "url": "Origins"
        }
    ]
}
```

What's more - i'm getting the exact same response for all other api endpoints (`GET /assets`, `GET /jobs` etc).

I'm sure it's quite simple issue to solve and i'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

I had used Media Services long time back (so I may be wrong) but I think there's an issue with your endpoint. Even though the default endpoint for connecting to media service is `https://media.windows.net/`, however, when implementing REST wrapper, we would need to first connect to this URI to find out if Media Service is redirecting us to a new URI or not.

Please ensure that this issue is not causing the problem you're facing. I also wrote some blog posts (though now quite old) about consuming Media Services REST API which you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/10/10/windows-azure-media-service-part-iii-managing-assets-via-rest-api/.

Comment: Well...the guide says that i need to use different URI if response code will be 301. It's 200 right now but i've just tried to fire exact same request to returned `odata.metadata` and it's working! Thanks for pointing this out :) Looks like a issue with reponse codes of WMS though